# rake command line

Tags: environment-variables, ruby

Is there a way in Ubuntu to have rake commands (Ruby) available on the command line?

I solved adding the following line to bashrc, but I think there should be a better way.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

Have I forgot something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RVM, it's a really great system to manage you ruby version and add all command needed in your PATH.

Comment: +1 RVM is wonderful.  Somewhat overkill if you are only using it to export the PATH, but it has a *LOT* of very useful features.

Answer (score 0):

That is sufficient to allow you to run all executables that were installed from gems for Ruby 1.8 from the command line without using the full path. They are technically available already but you have to type the full path eg.

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/some-command arguments
```

Adding `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin` to your $PATH is a perfectly valid shortcut to allow you to use the executables as normal commands eg.

```
some-command arguments
```